# Access out of loop value inside golang template's loop

Tags: templates, go

I have this struct :

```
type Site struct {
    Name string
    Pages []int
}
```

I pass an instance of `Site` to a [template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/).

If I want to write a list of all pages, I do

```
{{range .Pages}}
    <li><a href="{{.}}">{{.}}</a></li>
{{end}}
```

Now, what's the simplest way to use the `Name` field inside the loop (for example to change the `href` to `Name/page`) ?

Note that a solution based on the fact that the external object is the global one that was passed to the template would be OK.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You should know that the variable passed in to the template is available as `$`.

```
{{range .Pages}}
    <li><a href="{{$.Name}}/{{.}}">{{.}}</a></li>
{{end}}
```

(See the [text/template](http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#hdr-Variables) documentation under "Variables".)

Comment: What if I have a global variable 123 and inside a range I am trying to use the range's id as a global variable? So confusing... but how could I do this? I tried the following but it didn't quite work... http://pastebin.com/iAUtiLMq

Answer (score 18):

What about:

```
{{$name := .Name}}
{{range $page := .Pages}}
    <li><a href="{{$name}}/{{$page}}">{{$page}}</a></li>
{{end}}
```

Or simply make `Pages` a map with Name as value?

```
type Site struct {
    Pages map[string]string
}


{{range $page, $name := .Pages}}
    <li><a href="{{$name}}/{{$page}}">{{$page}}</a></li>
{{end}}
```

Comment: The first solution is about the same than mine. The second one isn't suited : the name isn't the name of the page but of the site.

Answer (score 12):

It looks like there's no simpler solution than to explicitly declare a variable for the outer object (or its properties) :

```
{{$out := .}}
{{range .Pages}}
    <li><a href="{{$out.Name}}/{{.}}">{{.}}</a></li>
{{end}}
```

**EDIT :** this answer isn't the right one any more, look at chowey's one instead.

Comment: There's nothing ridiculous about this. I've done this before. It does what it says. Clarity > brevity.

Comment: @JimPaek There's no shortcut to the object that was passed to the template ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was wrong. You could do something like: range $index, $page := .Pages and then I believe "." remains the original pipeline of the template. Edit: to be tested

Comment: @JimPaek It doesn't work : you can declare the variables like this but `{{.}}` is still the iterated value (that is it's equal to `$page`) and `{{.Name}}` thus makes a template error.

Comment: The philosophy of templates is very far from the one of Go code. My problem is that I didn't yet grasp the underlying logic.

Comment: This may not have been the most accurate answer to the OP's question, but it helped me because if you want to range over the root ( . ) as a slice or map you can't seem to do it any other way.

Comment: @bfrederi note that OP is also the answerer here ;)